# Elegant constructor states, reducing duplicates

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is really interesting me:

Is there a way to make states in a constructor more elegant then this:

```
state = {
    team1: 0, team2: 0, team3: 0, team4: 0
}
```

All values are identical, so is there way to shorten it and make it more elegant?

Thanks!

Comment: How is this "inelegant"? It's direct, to the point, and reeadable. I'd argue it's *wrong*, since you just need an array, which also makes it more extensible, but that's a separate discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an object and create a for loop that adds a key `'team' + index` with the value `0` to this object in every iteration:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const state = {};

    for(let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
      state['team' + i] = 0;
    }

    this.state = state;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: What if there are also pairs like: differentKey: 0 ?

Comment: @Barth Just create a helper function to return an appropriate object. Also, if you're doing this, it's fair indication that you should be using a data structure like an array instead.